# Cannot run OAuth2 with Okta using angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth-2.0, nativescript, angular-oauth2-oidc

I would like to develop an auth module for an Angular app. I use Okta as an identity provider and `angular-oauth2-oidc` is my choice to implement the auth workflow. I am trying to follow this guide https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/12/04/angular-7-oidc-oauth2-pkce but I am having trouble and get an error message if I run the web app. How can I make this example code to work?

**auth.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        RegisterFormComponent,
        SignInFormComponent,
        SignInPage,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(AUTH_ROUTES),
        HttpClientModule,
        OAuthModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthNgOauth2OidcService,
    ]
})
export class AuthModule {
}
```

**auth-ng-oauth2-oidc.service.ts**

```
export class AuthNgOauth2OidcService implements AuthService {

    authConfig: AuthConfig = {

        // Url of the Identity Provider
        issuer: environment.authIssuer,

        // URL to redirect the user to after login
        redirectUri: environment.authRedirectUri,

        // The application is registered with this id at the auth-server
        clientId: environment.authClientId,

        // Set the scope for the permissions the client should request
        // The first four are defined by OIDC
        // Request offline_access to get a refresh token
        scope: 'openid profile email offline_access',
    };

    public constructor(
        private authService: OAuthService,
    ) {
        this.authService.configure(this.authConfig);
        this.authService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
        this.authService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin().then();
    } 
}
```

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "~8.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.5.2",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.4.0",
    "angular-auth-oidc-client": "^10.0.10",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^8.0.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "mathjs": "^6.2.3",
    "nativescript-angular": "~8.0.1",
    "ng-oidc-client": "^1.0.7",
    "oidc-client": "^1.10.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

**error**

```
angular-oauth2-oidc.js:1346 error loading discovery document TypeError: this.interceptor.intercept is not a function
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1228)
    at DefaultOAuthInterceptor.push../node_modules/angular-oauth2-oidc/fesm5/angular-oauth2-oidc.js.DefaultOAuthInterceptor.intercept (angular-oauth2-oidc.js:3927)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1228)
    at HttpXsrfInterceptor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.js:1821)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1228)
    at HttpInterceptingHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http.js:1865)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http.js:1048)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:61)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:51)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
```

```
core.js:5847 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.interceptor.intercept is not a function
TypeError: this.interceptor.intercept is not a function
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1228)
    at DefaultOAuthInterceptor.push../node_modules/angular-oauth2-oidc/fesm5/angular-oauth2-oidc.js.DefaultOAuthInterceptor.intercept (angular-oauth2-oidc.js:3927)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1228)
    at HttpXsrfInterceptor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.js:1821)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1228)
    at HttpInterceptingHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http.js:1865)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http.js:1048)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:61)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:51)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:53)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:852)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at zone.js:913
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:24340)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

Comment: I don't think you could use angular-oauth2-oidc, it's designed for web apps running in browser, not for a native app. Did you check this plugin, [oauth2-oidc-client](https://github.com/EdSaleh/oauth2-oidc-client)?

Comment: I get this error in the webapp client, I didnt test it for the nativeapp build. But overall I need an OAuth client for both builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try adding this in your providers in auth.module.ts :**

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: AuthNgOauth2OidcService,
        multi: true
    },
    ]
```

Comment: Where does the GeneralInterceptor come from?

Comment: Edited try now.

Comment: Thanks, the error is gone, but how can I now inject the `AuthNgOauth2OidcService` into a component? I cannot use di like before ```constructor(authService: AuthNgOauth2OidcService){}``` because I removed the single AuthNgOauth2OidcService from the provider.

Comment: I don't know if it's working right if I don't have access to the service in another component.

Comment: As per the error this fix will work... I dont think there would be a problem when injecting this to components. Since i have done it my self while implementing Okta SAML and Okta OAuth.

Comment: Do you have an open-source example project?

Comment: I'm afraid I dont. Once i worked are highly confidential and I cannot share. But as per my experience Okta OAuth 2 is the easiest of them all. It has good documentation too.